# Salesforce Auto Number Standard Field Reser

Tags: apex, fields, standard

While creating an object, there is a standard field 'Name' in salesforce.

I have send that to auto number {0000} with start number 1 , once started saving records can we reset the value again to start from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reset the `autonumber` field to 1 again. You need to change the field type.

Refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005195&type=1) article from Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

> Auto-number fields only ever contain the numbers which the field has generated on its own. The truth is, you can jam anything you want in there. The loophole is that you can change the “field type” of a field from Auto-number to Text or from Text to Auto-number. For instance, you can change an Auto-number to Text temporarily so you can modify some of the numbers that had been assigned previously, and then change it back to Auto-number so it will continue assigning numbers to new records.

Yes, You can reset Auto-Number  fields by reassigning the field type. auto-number fields is not an unique fields. If the field is marked as an auto-number field, it will not duplicate unless someone edits the field and changes the type to Text, then re-edits and sets it back to Auto-number.

Answer (score 1):

You you can do this. Follow this steps:

Follow these steps to change the display format of the Auto-Number field and define a starting number

1. Click on Your Name | Setup | Build | Customize | Object Name | Fields
2. Click Edit next to the Auto-Number field you want to modify
3. Change the Display Format and Next Number you want to be displayed for your records. And click Save.
4. You will receive a pop-up with the following message: “This may result in duplicate number. Are you sure?”
5. Click Ok

[How do I reset/restart an auto number field?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005195&type=1)